# Webpack2 Error - Module Not Found

Tags: javascript, path, webpack, webpack-2

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/react/react.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './lib/React' in '/var/www/homelyfe/hl-app/node_modules/react'
 @ ./~/react/react.js 3:17-39
 @ ./app/index.js

ERROR in ./~/react-dom/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './lib/ReactDOM' in '/var/www/homelyfe/hl-app/node_modules/react-dom'
 @ ./~/react-dom/index.js 3:17-42
 @ ./app/index.js
```

In my `index.js` (which webpack2 seems to be picking up correctly), when I do

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
```

I get the above error. It seems, webpack is unable to find react. I have react & react-dom dependencies installed in `package.json`.

**My webpack.config.js is:**

```
const path = require("path");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const parts = require( "./webpack.config.parts" );
const PATHS = {
   app : path.join( __dirname, "app" ),
   build : path.join( __dirname, "build" )
};    
const common = {
   entry : {
      app : "./app/index.js"
   },
   output : {
      filename : "run.build.js",
      path : PATHS.build
   },
   resolve : {
      alias : {
         assets : path.resolve( __dirname, "app/assets" ),
         components : path.resolve( __dirname, "app/components" )
      },
      extensions : [ "js", "jsx" ]
   }
};
var config;
switch( process.env.npm_lifecycle_event ){
  case( "build-Prod" ): {
  ...
  }
  case( "start-Dev" ):
  default: {
        const eslintPath = path.join( __dirname, "/.eslintrc" );
        config = merge( common,
                                        parts.eslint( PATHS.app, eslintPath ),
                                        parts.babel( PATHS.app ),
                                        parts.devServer( PATHS.app ),
                                        parts.htmlWebpackPlugin());
    }
}
module.exports = config;
```

The webpack.config.parts file is:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
exports.babel = function( path ){
    var standardPresets = [
                            "react",
                            "es2015"
  ];
    var presets;
        presets = standardPresets;
    }
    return({
        module: {
            rules : [
                {
                    test : /\.jsx?$/,
          include : path,
                    use : [
                        {
                            loader: "babel-loader",
                            options : {
                                presets
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    });
};

exports.devServer = function() {
  return ({
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true,
      inline: true,
      stats: "errors-only"
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin({
        multiStep: true
      })
    ]
  });
};
exports.eslint = function( path, configFilePath ){
  return ({
    module: {
      rules : [
            {
                test : /\.jsx?$/,
                enforce : "pre",
        include : path,
                use : [
                    {
                        loader : "eslint-loader",
                        options : {
                            configFile : configFilePath
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
  });
};
exports.htmlWebpackPlugin = function( ) {
  return ({
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: "title"
      })
    ]
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error a few moments ago. After espending a lot of time, I found the solution.

In your `resolve.extensions` note that the extensions includes the leading dots. In that way you have to replace it with the following:

```
extensions : [ ".js", ".jsx" ]
```

Changing that, your problem should be fixed.